# innerHTML onClick issue

Tags: html, cross-browser, onclick, innerhtml

I am trying to change the content of the div which is a part of the parent page using the child page. In order to update the content, I use innerHTML. The contents appear just fine but the onclick event on the images does not work. Here is my code, the code works in Mozilla firefox but does not work in Chrome and Safari. Also, it does not work on iPad safari browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEMP</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>         
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    //this is the parent element
                    parent.document.getElementById('hd').innerHTML = document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fakeshare" style="float: left;margin-top: -30px;z-index:1000000;position: absolute;vertical-align: middle">    
        </div>
        <!-- this is the content I try to populate in the parent element -->
        <div id = "temp" style="visibility: hidden">
        <div style="float:left">
            <img id="backbtn2" class="imgtopbutton" src="images/facebook-cancel.png" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)" align="left" style="margin-left:12px;margin-top:10px"/>
            <img class="imgtopbutton" src="images/facebook-post.png" align="right" style="margin-top:-31px;margin-left:545px" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)">
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the element with `id="hd"`?

Comment: What do you mean by parent page and child page? Are you using `iframe`?

Comment: it is part of the parent page.

Comment: I am using modal dialog. The child page is loaded in modal dialog and the hd element is part of the parent page which works as the header of this modal dialog.

Comment: Are both the parent page and child page in same domain?

Comment: yes they are. I am testing them in my local webserver and they both are in same domain.

Comment: Ok, can you post the parent HTML also? Or create a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
$("#hd").html($("#temp").html());
```

Comment: OK, need to see your parent HTML.

Comment: Try `console.log(document);` and see what you see in the DOM of the document.

Comment: I kind of solved my problem. But, the question would have been different for my answer so I will mark you correct for this one.

Comment: @VendettaDroid Can you explain what the actual issue was?

Answer (score 1):

Try using $('#hd').parent().html($('#temp').html());

Comment: I tried it, but it does not update the content of #hd. Looked at the content from chromes debug view.